# Angular reusable directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create reusable directives by doing the following:

```
    a.directive("easyuiLinkbutton1", function () {
return {
    template: function ($element, $attributes) {
        return '<a easyui-linkbutton iconCls=' + $attributes.iconcls + 'plain="false"></a>'
    }
 };
});

a.directive("easyuiLinkbutton", function (caseMVCService) {
return {
    //restrict: "E",
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $(elem).linkbutton({ iconCls: attrs.iconCls });
    }
  };
});

 <a easyui-linkbutton1 iconCls="icon-cut" path="api/case" onclick="newCase" plain="false"></a>
```

Seems like I am having a problem at the following line:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $(elem).linkbutton({ iconCls: attrs.iconCls });
    }
```

Because second directive is called from a template function and no scope is available and also a parameter attrs does not carry values from the first directive.

I am trying to have a reusable directive 'easyuiLinkbutton'. Am I dong it correctly?

Thanks

Added more code.

```
<div easyui-linkbutton1 iconCls="icon-cut" path="api/case" onclick="newCase" plain="false"></div>
</div>

link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        newHTML = $compile('<a easyui-linkbutton iconCls=' + attrs.iconcls + 'plain="false"></a>')(scope);
        elem.append(newHTML);
    }
```

Comment: My fault. Fixing code.

Comment: Replacing the whole element is not possible unless you specify `replace: true`, which is a deprecated option. So you are trying to do something, which is not quite possible (if you don't want to use deprecated options).

Comment: What if I do something like I just added to my original code?

Comment: You don't need to call `$compile` manually if you don't intend to replace the element (which you should do in compile phase, not the link phase).

Comment: I have moved code into controller, but without $compile it does not get into second directive.